# SwiftUI View textfield not binding to ViewModel properties

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating a user signup with a NavigationView. The user enters an email, then they must enter
a username, password, etc.

After the user enters text the navigation link becomes active so they can continue to the next view and enter more details.

However the data entered is not binding with the properties in the ViewModel, I am using one ViewModel for all the data entry views in the NavigationView stack.

Why are the properties not binding/saving in the SignupViewModel? I know they aren't because I tried printing them after tapping the NavigationLink...

Thank you!

---

```
// ViewModel for all views in the stack

class SignupViewModel: ObservableObject {

   var email = ""
   var username = ""
   var password = ""
   var reconfirmPassword = ""

   func sendEmailCode() { } // sends secret code to email for verification
  
}
```

---

```
// 1st view in NavigationView stack

struct SignupEmailView: View {

    @ObservedObject var signupViewModel = SignupViewModel()

    var emailContinueDisabled: Bool {
        signupNavigationViewModel.email.isEmpty
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                HStack {

                    Image(systemName: EMAIL_ICON)
                        
                    TextField("enter your e-mail", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.email )
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                }
                    .modifier(DetailsTextFieldModifier())

                NavigationLink("continue", destination: ConfirmCodeView())
                    .disabled(emailContinueDisabled)

                Spacer() 
            }
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
      }
  }
```

---

```
// 2nd view in NavigationView stack

struct ConfirmCodeView: View {

    @ObservedObject var signupNavigationViewModel = SignupNavigationViewModel()
   
    var codeContinueDisabled: Bool {
        signupNavigationViewModel.emailCode.isEmpty
    }
    
    var body: some View {

            VStack {

            TextField("Enter code sent to your email", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.emailCode)

            NavigationLink("confirm", destination: SignupUsername())
           .disabled(codeContinueDisabled)

            Spacer()

            }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
   
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using computed property which they are not supported until today in SwiftUI Views, try to use **State**, **Binding** or **ObservableObject** directly.

---

```
struct SignupEmailView: View {
    
    @StateObject var signupViewModel = SignupViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Image(systemName: EMAIL_ICON)
                        
                    TextField("enter your e-mail", text: $signupViewModel.email)
                      .autocapitalization(.none)  
   
                }
                .modifier(DetailsTextFieldModifier())

                NavigationLink("continue", destination: ConfirmCodeView())
                  .disabled(signupViewModel.email.isEmpty) // <<: Here

                Spacer()

            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
      }
  }
```

---

```
struct ConfirmCodeView: View {
    
    @StateObject var signupNavigationViewModel = SignupNavigationViewModel()

    var body: some View {

            VStack {

            TextField("Enter code sent to your email", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.emailCode)

            NavigationLink("confirm", destination: SignupUsername())
             .disabled(signupNavigationViewModel.emailCode.isEmpty)  // <<: Here

            Spacer()

            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)


    }

}
```